# From Chrome extension, how to prevent Chrome from also automatically requesting resources from response’s rel=preload Link response headers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api, http2, preload

I have written a webextension for Chrome which can query bookmarks to see if the sites are still online.

I use the fetch API for querying the sites.
This works fine, but I have found an issue with one bookmark:

When fetching "https://victoryroadvgc.com", Chrome automatically also requests JS & CSS resources from HTTP `Link` response headers with `rel=preload` params; like this (wrapped for readability):

```
link: </min/d77e9.css>; rel=preload; as=style,
 </wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js>; rel=preload; as=script,
 </min/0d640.js>; rel=preload; as=script,
 </min/02cea.js>; rel=preload; as=script,
 </wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/js/webfontloader.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script
```

…which definitely is unwanted behaviour.
If I fetch that URL from the Chrome console, it does not request the additional resources.

The code I use to check if a site is available looks like this:

```
const request = await fetch(bookmark.url);

return (request.status !== 404);
```

Things I have tried to prevent this, but didn't work:

- Setting the "no-cors" mode for the request
- Setting the "Content-Type" header to "text/plain"
- Using XHMLHttpRequest instead of the fetch API

Why is the extension behaving like this and can I prevent this somehow?

Comment: I have done a bit more research and the reponse to the main request contains link headers to the additional resources of the page. Can I somehow ignore those headers?

Comment: You can probably strip those headers by using chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.

Comment: Try adding a `{ method: 'HEAD' }` argument to the fetch call in your code, so it’ll make a HEAD request instead; like this: `await fetch(bookmark.url, { method: 'HEAD' })`. (For the particular purpose described in the question, that’s better regardless, because it seems for what you’re having your extension do, you don’t need the response body anyway — all you want your code to do is to check the response’s HTTP status code. So you can achieve that just be making a `HEAD` request rather than the default `GET` a fetch call will otherwise make if you don’t explicitly give it a `method` to use.)

Comment: What messages is the browser logging in the devtools console?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question to make it clear that the cause here is the HTTP `Link` header `rel=preload` parameter. For more details, see the Preload spec at https://w3c.github.io/preload and the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content MDN article. (I also checked the requests and responses for https://victoryroadvgc.com/ to see if HTTP/2 Push might  be at play here, too — but it’s not; that site’s not using HTTP/2 Push.)

Comment: I have tried using the "HEAD" method like you suggested and that fixes the initial issue, but sadly quite a few reachable URLs return status 404 for HEAD requests, propably because they only implicitly implemented handlers for GET requests.

Comment: The console output when inspecting the web applications background page states, that the requested resources could not be loaded, because CORS headers are missing. That's why I even noticed that requests that shouldn't even be sent are executed.